# How to fix add_action?

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the piece of code that I believe is causing a fatal error on my WordPress site when trying to install a theme:

```
add_action( 'init', 'create_post_type', 0 );
```

The error I receive is:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare create_post_type() (previously declared in /home/content/30/4376030/html/wp-content/plugins/tsw-custom-listing/tsw-custom-listing.php:44) in /home/content/30/4376030/html/wp-content/themes/dolceclassifieds/functions.php on line 551

How can I prevent this error?

Comment: Unfortunately, this is a bit too broad for this site. No one here could even start without seeing that code and, even so, few are going to want to debug it for you. Your best bet is to hire someone to look at the code, or find a volunteer.

Comment: It looks like one of your plugins (`tsw-custom-listing`) uses the same function name (`create_post_type`) as the theme you want to install (`dolceclassifieds`). Maybe you can contact the theme and/or the plugin developer, and ask them to change the name of the function to something that is less likely to cause a conflict. For example `tsw_create_post_type` or `dolce_create_poste_type`.

Comment: Thank you jh1711!  That worked!  It is not a plug in I used, so I was just able to delete it.  You saved me from more hours of frustration!

Comment: To prevent this error, plugin/theme developers need to use proper namespacing and use the function_exists check if a function can be overridden. A function called create_post_type might exist in many themes/plugins so it should be called like tsw_create_post_type to prevent conflicts.

Answer (score 0):

Open your theme function file `themes/dolceclassifieds/functions.php` and go to line 551, find the function name and add prefix in the function name. then find out that action hook in that file and insert the new function name.

```
add_action( 'init', 'insert_here_new_function_name', 0 );
```

Hope it will solve your issue. but if you are not a coder then will be great to use a coder. Otherwise it can break any other function, if these are connected to other code.